# Magento call a .phtml file in template with product collection

Tags: php, magento, object

I can call a .phtml file to my .phtml template like a list.phtml.

```
<?php 
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('goodtest/test.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

But in test.phtml i cannot call $_product values.

For example:

```
<?php 
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): 
?>
```

works

```
<?php echo $_product->getName() ?>
```

not works:

```
<?php 
      echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('goodtest/test.phtml')->toHtml();
    ?>
```

In the file: test.html: `<?php echo $_product->getName() ?>`.

Do I must load full collection in product again in each included file, how can i get $_product values in test.phtml most effective way?

Comment: Use 'catalog/product_list' block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two options:

1. You can load product by `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(<product_id>)` with id each time within foreach loop.
2. Use below

`echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setTemplate('goodtest/test.phtml')->toHtml();`

instead of

`echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('goodtest/test.phtml')->toHtml();`

Comment: hi thx i used getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setTemplate('goodtest/test.phtml')->toHtml(); but i cannot call echo $_product->getName() it stops page loading on that echo. How can I access $_product values? I need to send $_product object in that command like $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?

Comment: I have tested this code on my local server. Its working. May be you have missed some thing in your file.

Comment: Hi in list phtml i used
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/deliveryterms.phtml')->toHtml(); ?> but in the deliveryterms.phtml file i cant call <?php echo $_product->getName() ?> it stoprs, value $_product returns nothing ...

Answer (score 3):

You can assign template through controller like @example

```
$this->loadLayout();
$listBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')
            ->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')
            ->setCollection($collection);

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($listBlock);
    $this->renderLayout();
```